# Reference as last symbol in C++ function declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, function-declaration, ref-qualifier

Looking at Boost::Optional [optional class template header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/header_optional_optional_values.html#reference_operator_template) I come across this:

```
T const& operator*() const&
T&       operator*() &;
T&&      operator*() &&;
```

For the life of me I can't find this syntax anywhere else (a reference as the last symbol) I would assume it has something to do with overloading on the type(const l-val, l-val, r-val) of the object the operator belongs to, but I haven't seen this described anywhere.

Could someone tell me what this syntax means?

Comment: consider it applied to the type of `*this` for overload resolution on the hidden `this` parameter